# What does Compressor offer that HandBrake doesn't?

Tags: encoding, video-editing, final-cut-pro, compressor

Video encoding is a small hobby of mine and, while I'm familiar with HandBrake and have been dipping my toes into the far more capable and complicated world of Avisynth, I only recently learned that Apple apparently has its own encoding utility called Compressor.

I like to stick to first-party tools whenever it's practical for me, so I'd love to start using Compressor if it can fit somewhere into my personal workflow. But I'd rather not spend the $50 on it without knowing for sure that it can be useful for me. And there aren't any detailed breakdowns that I've been able to find for it.

So my question is, what, if anything, does Compressor offer a user that HandBrake doesn't, and vice versa? Does Compressor have all the same functionality and could just be a drop-in replacement for it altogether? Is it more/less efficient in its encoding? Aside from the cost and the open source vs closed source debate, is there any good reason to use one over the other for someone working exclusively with M1 Mac machines?

Comment: Price, of course!

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to make presets for FCPX, which can be quite useful.

Other than that I find the interface to be cumbersome, with the beachball coming up a lot. To the point that I find those aforementioned presets work quite a bit more quickly in FCPX.

I am currently experimenting with Shutter Encoder, which is a great front end for FFMPEG (like Handbrake) which has the advantage of preserving folder structure (v handy for mega batches.)